# Python: How do I refactor and structure code in this scenario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm quite stuck on structuring the code in this scenario. Can anyone help me with this?

| module.py

```
import asyncio

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls):
        self = cls()
        await self.func()
        return self

    async def func(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Some other async code here
        self.a = 12

    def reg(self, ev):
        def decorator(func):
            self.d[ev] = func()
            retun func
        return decorator

    def reg2(self, ev, func):
        self.d[ev] = func
```

| main.py

```
import asyncio
from module import Server

async def main():
    ser = await Server.create()
    # This would be another way... but i find the other way one neater
    serv.reg2('msg', some_handler)

# I want to decorate and register this using
# reg func; but since object is not created yet
# how do i acomplish this?
# @ser.reg('msg')
async def some_handler():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Some key points of my aim:

- The function 'some_handler' is never used other than the time for register. That is, the function soley exists to be registered and is not used anywhere else.
- Since Server class needs an asynchronous initialisation, it cannot be done globally.
- (I dont know whether this point is helpful) Generally only one Server instance is created for a single program. There wont be any other instance even in other modules.

How do I model my code to satisfy this senario? I have mentioned an alternate way to register the function, but I feel I am missing something, as some_handler isn't used anywhere else. I have thought about making Server class into a metaclass to do registering and converting the main() and some_handler() as parts of the metclass's class but I'm seeking for different views and opinions.

Comment: You could define `some_handler` either locally inside `main` (using `ser.reg` as a decorator after you've created `ser` in that scope) or as an instance method of `Server`, depending on whether its functionality makes sense as something for `Server` to handle.  There's no law saying that decorators need to be global functions or need to only be used on global functions.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I guess it will workout and does make sense. But then one drawback is that testing will involve some additional work.